# Why does Google still use paging instead of progressive loading?

Tags: pagination, infinite-scroll

As a designer I believe "Page system" is less efficient than progressive loading inside a single page.
However it is still widely used on many websites including Google’s search results.

[image: Google Search pagination, offering links from "1" to "10"]

Maybe there is an important advantage of the pagination system that I am missing.

Can you help me to figure out why it is still commonly used?

Comment: In what way do you believe progressive load is more efficient? Are we talking about 'user finding what they want' efficient, or computational efficiency? In my (anecdotal) experience, I find infinite scrolling pages to be worse on both counts.

Comment: Google does use infinite scroll when searching for images, though.

Comment: I personally find progressive loading, for anything other than social media, extremely annoying and "un-user friendly". If you are searching for something specific and find it on a page, then you know where it is and can deep link to it. If you leave the results and go back, you know where to go to quickly get to where you left off. Not to mention there is less memory required to render the redundant results in progressive loading.

Comment: I prefer pagination for most things. But if you want to see search with progressive loading, fire up duckduckgo.com and you can see how it compares.

Comment: Because everybody except web designers caught up in latest trends (i.e. especially **users**) knows that progressive loading is utterly awful ux. Browser eventually slows down to a crawl, and it's usually impossible to find the same thing more than once; even if you can, it can take hours, and "search in page" doesn't work until you manually scroll far enough to reach the desired content.

Comment: @TimBJames, you can't deep link to Google results, simply because everybody gets different results on the same query.

Comment: Progressive loading has it's places.  While others would love it every moment.  But few would enjoy it if a book were a long continual scroll of paper (hopefully)! There's a reason even PDFs have pages, and it's not just its printability

Comment: I find progressive loading annoying on social media, too, because then I forget to stop and take a break. Of course that's what they're trying to do.

Comment: Btw "as a designer" you're badly wrong and I'd go so far as to say *unqualified for your job*. Pushing ux that users almost universally consider *awful* onto them because you have a contrary-to-fact and contrary-to-users "belief" that your way is "more efficient" is... uhg.

Comment: Related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28351/why-paginate-page-break-an-infinitely-scrolling-dynamic-list

Comment: As always, there's a relevant XKCD comic. https://xkcd.com/1309/ "Maybe we should give up on the whole idea of a "back" button. "Show me that thing I was looking at a moment ago" might just be too complicated an idea for the modern web."

Comment: Because infinite scrolling is annoying and bad, especially on phones, I'd be scrolling through some stuff and then I accept a phone call or check the map or something and when I come back the page has reset itself and I have scroll through ALLL items again for ten minutes just to get to where I was, so annoying. It's not a problem with pages though.

Comment: @user51343, well not quite *infinite scroll* on the images page, something of a hybrid between that and pagination.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+second+page+meme&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5ivOKvorXAhVV8WMKHQdoDXwQ_AUICigB&biw=1268&bih=949) has a [second](https://xkcd.com/1334/) page?!

Comment: As a user, I believe designers who think a neverending, constantly changing page that can never be reproduced twice in a row and can never be saved, printed, or even viewed in its entirety is beneficial should be gently punched in the nose.

Comment: Almost every time you find result you need on first 10 result, So if there is auto load and you find your result on 9th record, Do you really wish that google load unwanted results ??

Comment: Many of these fancy web-design fads of the last years may be neat to look at the first few times, be it caroussels, infinite scroll, lazy loading or even (shriek) horizontal layouts, but then they suck from a user's point of view. E.g., with lazy loading one gets different results for incremental search, depending on how much has been scrolled over; crazyness. Also, many of those magick apparatuses destroy conversion rates, something that seems to not exist for a perceived 95%+ majority of webdesigners. Bubble-Bursting read/blog: https://www.crazyegg.com/blog/ugly-website-design/ .

Comment: Also: I really recommend to strike "why don't they **use** X, **yet**", "why do they **still use** X" and all variants thereof (regex: `(still|allready)?.*(use|using).*(yet)?`) from your list of idioms. I always get frightened when hearing that, because it's often enough a red flag indicating blind faith in something. "Yo brother, work for us, we're already using .net, you know" was something I heard quite often 10 years ago. It sounded like they seriously believed that .net was the One True Thing to use. Know what I mean? My newest favourite acronym fits nicely: A.S.S., Always Stay Skeptical.

Comment: Here is my point of view : When an user reaches the end of the first page we can assume he haven't find what he is looking for. Then, why don't we help him by loading automatically more results or inviting him to precise its search ?
It seems much more user friendly to me than showing 10 tiny links to jump to another page.  And i am not talking about *infinite scrolling*, simply to auto-load next results

Comment: @R.. The worse part about infinite scrolling on Facebook is trying to find something, because as you scroll, Facebook will _remove/unload_ the top of the page! So CTRL-F never works! You can't just hold `END` for a while and search, because you probably skipped the chunk it was in.

Comment: @R..: Progressive loading might suck on Facebook, but it works flawlessly for me on YouTube. IMO the general bloat is the problem, not the scrolling model.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Tell me how it works when you click on something you want to see, navigate a few more links forward, then want to get back to *where you were before* using the back button.

Comment: @R..: It does that just fine as long as I'm on YouTube. If I click a link to somewhere outside then it doesn't work, but I never need to do that (and normally I open an external link in a new tab anyway).

Comment: why you think "progressive loading" is better than paging?
with progressive loading, how to scroll to last item?

Comment: Infinite scrolling requires JavaScript, manual pagination still works without it.

Comment: To me the most annoying thing in infinite scrolling is that I have no idea how much stuff is there that I might have to go through. It could be just the visible page plus one row, or 100 more pages, and I will find that out only once my scrolling attempts no longer cause further data to appear, and I have no idea how long it will take to reach that point. With pagination, I would know immediately that there are 100 pages, so I can decide if I actually want to go through so much data or try something else instead.

Comment: @Renauld Control - as a user I want to be in control what the site does, I'd hate it if I quickly scroll down to glance at all results and then, when I want to look at their summaries the page either automatically switches to page 2 or bothers me with a popup. This is one thing infinite scroll gets right, when implemented properly, it does not affect your interaction with the already visible part of the page while loading more stuff below.

Comment: Infinite scrolling sucks, ultimately.  Its flashy and annoying.

Comment: Infinite scrolling is complete crap.  You might as well ask: "Why do google 'still' not use flaming logos".  The question is really silly, and the "still" in the title is vastly confusing.

Comment: Funnily enough google uses infini scroll or an even worse manual version for their youtube playlists and results. The result is one of the most annoying and useless UI's I have ever seen. Managing or even viewing a video from a playlist that has many hundred entries, or even thousands is impossible, extremely and unnecessarily time consuming and inconsistent.

Comment: @phresnel Personally, I *Never* use Always. Oops! (falls in to a black hole)

Comment: Infinite scrolling is awful *even* on social media.   I am often 3-4 days behind on Facebook, and forget it.  I'll get about 18 hours in, and something will happen and the app will reset or the page will redraw, and I'm back at the top again going "well I guess I'm not meant to see that content, buhbye." .... Especially on mobile, God help you if you page out to fact-check a comment before you hit post, come back, app reset, comment gone, and you can't even find the article again.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised about the amount of tech related answers here. UX is about people, start with thinking about users. See my answer below.

Comment: @Renaud Because maybe the user wants to search for a string, but can't because it's on a part of the page that hasn't loaded yet. Because maybe the user is scrolling down by dragging the scrollbar, and the scale changes whenever new content is loaded at the bottom so they end up scrolling directly from "90% done with the first page of material" to "90% done with the first two pages" and need to find their place again. Because maybe they have a low memory system that will start crawling when all that is loaded. Because maybe they have Javascript turned off and would still like the page to work.

Comment: If something is a horribly bad idea, should I downvote, or upvote, the question?

Comment: Seems practical to me that Google search results are also search engine friendly. I think it's just a matter of principle for Google to use pagination and be consistent with what they ask others to do with their own websites.

Comment: reason 1: Google search is so good that you most of time find within 10 results.                                   reason 2: it is important to see last result equally as first. if infinite scroll fired, distraction happens

Comment: The OP might mean... why doesn't Google think they can show more than 10 _actual_ results per page in 2022?

Comment: My current search has over 8 million results. There is no possible way I could ever scroll past even the first few hundred without pagination.

Comment: I don't know how long Google has been doing this, but I'm now seeing a "More Results" button at the bottom of my search results instead of pagination.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

Infinite scroll has its uses, but a search result page **is not one of them**. Infinite scroll relies on discovery and exploration. This works well for when you're not looking for anything in particular; when you're sifting through a massive amount of data *until you find something that hooks your interest*. This format lends itself extremely well for social media with newsfeeds, or inspiration platforms like Pinterest.

> You may measure the benefits of infinite scrolling with the example of a Facebook news feed. By unspoken agreement, users are aware that they won’t get to see everything on the feed, because the content is updated too frequently. With infinite scrolling, Facebook is doing it’s best to expose as much information as possible to the users and they are scanning and consuming this flow of information.

Search results are all about **finding what you need.**

> Pagination is good when the user is searching for something in
>   particular within the list of results, not just scanning and consuming
>   the flow of information.

Google wants to show you relevant data. Pagination tells you where the search results are located (page) and in which order they match your criteria. This helps to estimate how much time it’ll take to find what you're actually looking for and helps you find results back.

Google has experimented in the past with loading times. Turns out, even with a slightly longer delay in loading, people are more likely to abandon the search. Infinite scroll is rather heavy on performance, so this would multiply this abandoning rate.

More here: https://uxplanet.org/ux-infinite-scrolling-vs-pagination-1030d29376f1

Comment: Also for search in general pagination has the benefit you can relate to your last search or someone else's search - i.e. you can say "the 2nd result on page 3" while it's quite hard to find the 42th result in a progressive loading setup - assuming 20 results per page.

Comment: @Darkwing Unless you're using the same Google localization, the results will wildly vary.

Comment: @JohnHamilton Well, it's likely I would talk with someone in the same region or redo the same search also in the same localization. However, you are right that the argument isn't *that* strong for Google (but still relevant enough I'd say), I find reconsidering the same search and restarting on the page I stopped last time even more helpful in a lot of other cases - like looking through recommended movies, hotel rooms, cars on sale ordered by price/closeness etc. pp.

Comment: @Darkwing Oh, I'm not suggesting it's not useful but just not a really good means of presenting others with search results you have procured. I always use the international version of Google and I've had this problem with almost everyone I know. Though, as you have suggested, it's useful for a lot of other things.

Comment: @JohnHamilton Are you using touch devices or desktops/mouse driven devices? I would argue that it's partially a device issue, with mobile pagination is far more cumbersome to control. I do hate progressive tough - even on mobile - for it usually is so power-hungry at some point it crashes the browser and it's hard to re-engage then (on the other hand, good time to stop slacking off).

Comment: @JohnHamilton Google search result is _personalized_. If we both search for the word X then we may well get **completely different** results, regardless our geographic area (assuming we both have a Google account...)

Comment: I've upvoted this because it's true. Most searches are from people looking for something specific, and they expect it to show up at the top. If it doesn't, they'll try different search criteria rather than browsing further through the results. Anyone that knows SEO will tell you that the number of hits you get is directly related to how high up you are on the first page. In the top five, then you stand a chance of a click. If you're much further down than that, you may as well forget it. People don't even scan to the bottom of the first page most of the time, much less move onto the next page.

Comment: Most of these arguments would work if the question was "whats the point in having pagination on google results at all"

Comment: "[infinite scrolling] works well [...] when you're sifting through a massive amount of data until you find something that hooks your interest." I dispute that, since it breaks search within page.

Comment: Good explanation. I always find myself searching through multiple pages and thinking to myself  "okay, XYZ is on page 3..". So that's another benefit in terms of searching. It's an indicator to help you organize in your mind on-the-go

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. Pagination and infinite scrolling are just different interfaces to the same result set. So there's no reason why the paradigm of 'search results' shouldn't be interfaced through an infinitely scrolling list. 

There are of course differences in how these two interfaces can be utilized, for instance google can allow <noscript> on a paginated interface. And so there is definitely a more appropriate interface to use depending on your scenario. 

But flat-out saying that infinitely scrolling lists are not appropriate for search results is ill-conceived.

Comment: Another important point is that Google (like any other search engine out there) strives to give the most relevant content in the first few results. Ideally, just the first two or three links it gives should fulfill the query. Having the user need to even see there are other pages, let alone scrolling down potentially ad libitum, is a little failure from Google's perspective. The user should not have the impression there is a lot more relevant content: he should be fully satisfied by what he finds on the top of the page.

Comment: @Shadetheartist If all of your search results 
 were in one single vertical column, that would also be the same results just in a different format. And it would be incredibly annoying. Presentation matters incredibly much.

Comment: @Darkwing: "I would argue that it's partially a device issue, with mobile pagination is far more cumbersome to control." - with a mouse, progressively loading pages are almost unusable IMO. Everytime more content gets loaded, the total page length changes, and therefore also the position of the thumb on the scrollbar. The next moment I move the cursor by a pixel (while I'm still holding the mouse button pressed, given that I was dragging the thumb), I am suddenly above the non-thumb part of the scrollbar and the content gets shifted to a totally other place because the scrollbar now thinks ...

Comment: ... I want to fast-forward to another position. (I know I could use the mousewheel or click the up/down buttons on the scrollbar, but neither gives me as accurate a control about how fast to continuously move content along in accordance with my reading speed.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby The use-case made for infinite scrolling is when you don't know yet what you are looking for, so you couldn't type a search anyway. That's why it fits news feeds and the like, where information is offered and you just browse through it without a clear cut goal. (I'm still disliking performance issues and site size changes etc, but I see the benefit).

Comment: @Darkwing: I cannot imagine any situation where I might be scrolling to see what's there, but never want to search for something again that I read above - then, or after a (possibly unintentional) page reload.

Comment: "Infinite scroll has its uses, but a search result page is not one of them. Infinite scroll relies on discovery and exploration." First two sentences seem to contradict each other. Isn't search a synonym for discovery and exploration? It may even be a prime example of discovery and exploration with infinite scrolling (see duckduckgo for example).

Comment: @Trilarion Search results for information are quite specific; you want the most relevant information matching your specific criteria. Often you'll want to make a mental note of where you found the information since you're gathering multiple sources.  When it comes to images, it's more up to your own interpretation whether the results match your criteria. You'll then be looking for something until it hooks your interest. Then infinite scroll has a better chance to give you what you're looking for as you can keep going until you have a hit. Hence Google using infinite scroll for their Images.

Comment: I can "find what I need" using infinite scroll and claiming a search result page isn't a valid case for infinite scroll is rhetoric at this point, since you only begin to validate the claim halfway through this answer. Remove everything above the paragraph "Google wants" and the answer will be more succinct.

Comment: @JohnHamilton not just localization, but previous searches and whatnot will effect what comes up first, right? They at least do that for ads.

Comment: @Darkwing Sure, _the first time_ I visit the page, I might not know what I want. But when I come back to it an hour later because I want to show you something really cool that I found? _Then_ I want to search. That's the problem with designing a UI based on the assumption that there's only one way that users want to interact with the page: there's always another way.

Answer (score 143):

There is no official statement regarding this, so no one can give you a 100% accurate answer.

One of the biggest reasons might be the ad placement of Google.
They earn money with every search, and since they use pagination they can even earn money multiple times with only one search, try it yourself.

For example if you search for "toaster" (in Germany), these are the 1st and 2nd page ads:

[image: First Page top-ad]
[image: Search results, with ads to the right]

So in short, I think pagination fits Google's business goals.

Comment: +1, good point! Pagination is user friendly for search, but it definitely also serves their business goals.

Comment: There are ways to change ads while user scrolls, though it may be not as efficient.

Comment: duckduckgo for example uses infinite scrolling, so it seems even arbitrary, some do, others don't.

Comment: yeah, this is surely the answer to "why Google prefers it" ...   this is their original way of making money and still an important one.  Every click reloads new ads,  and they also charge more for the earlier pages-- much, much, much more for the first page.  (you bid for a combination of search terms and place and time and maybe more these days...  highest bid for that combination gets first ad slot)

Comment: "They earn money with every search" - do they? It says here that they only charge per each click on the add: https://adwords.google.com/home/

Comment: @RasmusLarsen I bet there is at least one person per search on the planet that clicks an ad :) But of course you are right, they charge per click.

Comment: @RasmusLarsen They charge per click, but impressions (showing up in search results regardless of whether clicked) factor into the bidding process on keyword ads, so every related search increases the final charge once someone clicks.

Comment: By that argument facebook - which has exactly the same business goals as Google (ads) - shouldn't use pagination either. Clearly since facebook can make it work, so could google. It's just horrible, horrible, horrible UX.

Comment: No, there is definitely a solution to ad-breaking and pagination. They just choose not to use it. Having ads on every page is no different to having ads on every infinite-page load.

Answer (score 107):

Since no one posted it yet, to me the main reason against infinite scrolling is shown in [this XKCD comic](https://xkcd.com/1309/):

[image: Maybe we should give up on the whole idea of a 'back' button. 'Show me that thing I was looking at a moment ago' might just be too complicated an idea for the modern web.]

The tool tip reads:

> Maybe we should give up on the whole idea of a 'back' button. 'Show me that thing I was looking at a moment ago' might just be too complicated an idea for the modern web.

[Here is the Explain XKCD page for the comic strip](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1309:_Infinite_Scrolling).

**Update 1:**

I just found [the hidden comment above](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/112957/why-does-google-still-use-paging-instead-of-progressive-loading/113001#comment182533_112957) that already mentioned this XKCD comic strip.

**Update 2:**

To clarify, why I do think my answer is valid here is: To me, the equivalent of the above

> "If I touch the wrong thing, I'll lose my place and have to start over"

is when clicking a SERP entry, going to the destination URL and then clicking the <kbd>Back</kbd> button.

This would usually return me to some other location than the previous SERP infinite scroll position where I left.

Comment: Whoa. XKCD has tooltips! That will help make sense of some of the comics I didn't get...

Comment: New idea: infinite scrolling tooltips...

Comment: @Andrew the tooltips are part of the comic, and the mystery. They won't provide you new clues,  but a second joke. For help in "getting them", the explainxkcd.com community website is a great resource (especially for people from different cultural and education backgrounds)

Comment: Everyone loves XKCD, but to be fair this isn't really an answer to the question, it's just a mildly related XKCD strip. Can you elaborate, specifically around how this relates to the Google experience?

Comment: @JonW Actually it's quite explanatory, particularly what the scrolling person says. For more explanation, see the comments on the question.

Comment: Thanks, @JonW. I know that I'm not as experienced as you guys with UX. To me, the main reason against virtually all infinite scrolling implementations (and therefore also against a Google one) is, that it doesn't "preserve state" and/or doesn't allow to get something like a book markable scroll position. Plus, accidentally pressing a wrong key (like `Home`) or clicking a search result and going back from there, returns you to something completely different as where you left. That's why I posted my answer here.

Comment: Slightly disingenuous, it is possible to preserve where in the scroll the user is, with modern JavaScript you can write to the URL without refreshing the page, which will be preserved in browser history, unlike using strings past the #

Comment: @Ben Keeping track of where the user was might be easy, but actually getting them back to there might not be. The user may have scrolled down through 20 requests worth of data - meaning if they leave the page and try to hit  back, all 20 of those requests either need to be compressed into one massive payload, or they are going to have to sit there while 20 requests load in sequence, or some other not-so-great approach to get them back to where they were - It's not uncommon for developers to just avoid the issue and leave the users to fend for themselves.

Comment: @Andrew I wrote the following script a long time ago to append the comic's tooltip in a `<p>` tag below the image: `$('<p>' + $('#comic img').attr('title') + '</p>').insertAfter($('#comic'));` I use it with a Chrome extension ([Panda Styler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/panda-styler-emoji/bogdgcfoocbajfkjjolkmcdcnnellpkb)) which runs it automatically on every page load.

Comment: @BlakeMann I believe there is such a concept as caching pages in the browser so they don't reload when you navigate back to them. I don't remember how it's done.

Comment: @Andrew Possibly, but that could be a lot of content to cache, and if it's dynamic content, caching doesn't really work great - that content could have changed by the time you come back to the page. In fact, I use a few lazy loading sites where as I'm scrolling, the next set of info includes some duplicates from the last one because in the time it's taken to scroll down the page, new content has been added. My point though is not so much that it can't be done, but that it's challenging and often _not_ done, leading to the perception stated in this answer not being so disingenuous after all.

Comment: @Andrew Holding 20 "pages" of results sounds like a memory hogging nightmare. Heck, the memory consumption issue on the page to begin with sounds like a good reason not to do it in the first place.

Comment: @jpmc26 Depends on the content (e.g. consider search engine results - that's hardly much) and how the results are stored. You could for instance store them (possibly cached) on the server statically and then just have the browser store the search terms and the scroll index.

Comment: @Andrew Congratulations. You've just reinvented paging. Another [relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1367/).

Comment: @jpmc26 ...No I didn't...? Paging requires explicit navigation, which was nowhere hinted or implied in my comments.

Comment: @Andrew If the front end is not storing results as it goes, it's paging them. Scrolling is not an effective mechanism for browsing through them this way, since there's no effective way to translate "vertical position" into what index you're currently on. At a bare minimum, you're going to build a fake "scroll bar" and do something like encode the current page and size in the fragment, unless you're willing to break the back button. You really, really are just reinventing paging in JavaScript, only with a worse UX, if you do what you described.

Comment: @jpmc26 Surely that's not the case! If the server caches results and/or produces a consistent set of results every time, paging is unnecessary. There are multiple ways to translate scrolling position: for one, JS can easily save and recall scroll positions; also, there are HTML anchors; lastly, you could have fixed-size data.

Comment: @jpmc26 You talk like you've thought of all things but this is very close-minded. There are many, many possibilities.

Comment: @Andrew Paging already requires that there is a consistent set of results (thought not necessarily a static set). It requires 3 inputs to be specified: a sort order, a number of results to fetch, and a start indicator (either an item or page number). From the front end, the sort order is often already specified for the user, but it is well defined in the application nonetheless. Caching the results server side does not change this for the client side. While it's true I've never tried to implement a fake infinite scroller, paging is easy to spot because of those three required inputs.

Comment: @jpmc26 You're missing the point entirely of infinite scrolling: from a user standpoint, it is **better** in some regards in that you don't have to explicitly click page numbers and wait for pages to load. See there's this thing called users who would like to be able to do things without a lot of work or time put into it. An infinite scrolling option that mitigates these concerns is more ideal than pagination. And if you keep missing the point I'm not going to bother replying to someone who is unable to comprehend the discussion.

Comment: @Andrew Except infinite scrolling on top of pagination doesn't make it more convenient. Clearing out old entries as you suggest means I can't search the page like I normally would, going backwards would be no more performant than having separate pages (probably worse). It just makes it difficult to navigate at all. That's been my experience with every single real world infinite scroller I've encountered, and your idea of turning it into a different UI for pagination doesn't solve the UX problems. It's more convenient to have good paging that works than crappy attempts at replacing paging.

Comment: It works great for Facebook on my phone. It would do just fine for search engine results. Pinterest doesn't really need searching and could get away with adding and removing content dynamically. Pagination is terrible for performance, so it's not even worth comparing. Pagination relies on waiting for the server to generate and send the next page over the internet. With infinite scrolling it can do this preemptively. Your latter comment is just stupid: there are use cases where infinite scrolling is a good option. I honestly feel like I'm talking to an idiot newbie coder.

Comment: @Andrew Let me ask you this, how far do you scroll down? Because after maybe about 20 loads, I'm seeing the site eat around a GB of RAM in Chrome. Which sounds like it would serious problem on a phone. Infinite scrolling only works when a few results are needed. For large sets when you actually want to interact with a good chunk of them, it really is a horrible and terrible way of trying to do it. Which defeats the "infinite" part completely. You may as well just make it a few results at that point. ...And I can't even figure out how to open an article to see if Back works.

Comment: @jpmc26 On Facebook on my phone, I scroll for a good 15+ pages' worth just fine. You can either use middle click to open in a new tab or press and hold and click on open in new tab.

Answer (score 95):

**Noscript Support**

In addition to the other answers above, infinite scroll is only possible with javascript enabled.  If Google wants to appeal to the widest possible userbase for their main page, then it is beneficial for them to display search results to people who do not have javascript enabled.

Infinite scroll has the added downside of hiding the footer of the page unless its position is fixed to the screen.

Comment: Why would Google want to make life easier for noscript users? If I understand correctly, all their revenue comes from (javascript-based) ads and analytics.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni If someone disables javascript knowingly, they wouldn't enable it even if google required it, and instead would go to some other service providing search. Then, being Google, you'd be losing potential users for your search engine as well as other products, just because you want to spite them for not allowing you to run your ad-related js. Not a very healthy relationship to have with potential users.

Comment: I doubt this is a real reason.  Not many people use Noscript.

Comment: @Federico Poloni: The ad revenue on Google.com itself is generated when a user clicks an ad, which can be recorded regardless of whether or not the user has javascript enabled.  

gerrit: I'm not just talking about people who use a specific plugin to disable javascript; I am talking about everyone who has javascript disabled, regardless of what they use, which is thought to be about 1% of users.  If Google has the option of getting 1% more ad revenue from this, then that would be a valid consideration for them to take into account.

Comment: This can't be the reason.  It would be trivial for Google to provide a UI that uses infinite scroll when JS is enabled, and pagination when JS is disabled.

Comment: Google has plenty of features that require javascript. 
They have no problem whatsoever to have an alternative implementation for those, who do not have js enabled/supported.

Comment: Unobtrusive javascript is a thing.

Comment: I can confirm that as a security conscious (read: paranoid) user, I browse with NoScript on by default, *and* I enable scripts from only specific `https://` subdomains very selectively, *and* if the website doesn't work within a couple of rounds of selectively-enable-and-reload, I will just stop using the site unless I *really have to* use it. I also intentionally use [the HTML-only DuckDuckGo page](https://duckduckgo.com/html) instead of the fully-featured one precisely because as a user I prefer the no-infinite-scroll and other simpler page behaviors.

Comment: I agree about the footer.   Google has on on the search results.  A footer is a great place to put links that users may need occasionally but which shouldn't be prominent.  Having things like "help" in the footer is better than having it hidden in a menu because users can find it using `ctrl-f`.

Comment: I think theoretically you could have infinite scroll without javascript by never ending the page load.  You'd need some event on scroll though.  Possibly an image/font load.

Answer (score 23):

Pagination works better for several reasons:

1. Because the resulting HTML isn't complete, some browsers display NOTHING, while others display what comes back.  So, browser compatibility would be one reason.
2. Because with pagination, Google can place sponsored ads at the top of each page; with infinite scrolling, that's more complicated to do
3. Because with infinite scrolling, the server (google) is still doing work, even though the user might not be doing anything.  With pagination, it is guaranteed that the user wants more data, because the click next page; with infinite scrolling, the server is still providing data, and there's no reason to think the user will be consuming that data
4. Because infinite scroll is a horrible memory pig

On the flip side,

With infinite scroll, the only benefit for the end user is that they do not need page navigation to find what they want: everything's on the page, and simple CTRL-F can help them hone in on something.  This trick does not work with pagination.

Other than that, I don't see much benefit to infinite scroll.

**EDIT**: Sorry, can't address all the comments without making a million comments myself, so I'll include them here, as they are relevant to the OP's question:

If you google "trump", Google will report "about 755,000,000" results were found.  Of them, only 12 are displayed.  The user's only requirement is, to keep asking for more.  That list of 755M results is residing somewhere on some Google server, but is not downloaded to the user's browser.  That's because pagination is used.

With infinite scrolling, there are several implementations of it.  Some is pseudo "infinite", where there are blocks (larger than a page; perhaps, 2 or 3 pages or more) which are privately downloaded and displayed a page at a time by the browser, and as the user scrolls down near the bottom of the block, another block is downloaded and displayed line by line or page by page.  This gives the appearance that the list is infinite, and is a very common implementation.

Another type of infinite scrolling is "true" infinite scrolling, whereby the server, in this example, flings all 755M results to the browser.  Here, the server determines the method to display:

It can be by way of a giant HTML, in which case, the full display may take a long time because the HTML is not, in fact, complete, and, the server is constantly working to send those 755M results down the pipe.  Or the server can serve up a response containing complete HTML and no data, but, also contains browser script (eg, JavaScript, VBScript, ActiveX, Java, or some other scripting component) fills up a data island, allowing the display to grow as the user scrolls around.

Which method is employed depends a lot on the type of data being served up.  For Google, the potential to fling down 755M results means that managing that on the browser would cause a huge amount of network traffic to result, as well as crashing most browsers as the amount of data becomes unwieldy.  But divvying up that 755M results is also unwieldy for Google, and is wasted effort since few people or systems will consume that much data.  So Google more efficiently manages that data by privately storing only 128 of those results on its side, and divvys up that data into blocks of about 14 pages.  The user sees 10 pages, but you can slide to the last page (page 10) and then see an additional 4 pages.  You'll also note that the query has resulted in "Page 14 of about 128 results", not "Page 14 of 62,916,667 pages in .98 seconds"

Other forms of infinite scrolling don't involve that much data, but definitely more than a few pages: a news source, for example.  US News and World Report today has 100 articles: it displays only 4 or 5, and in the background has downloaded about a dozen; you scroll down consuming that dozen, and when you get close to the last page of a dozen, another dozen or so is downloaded - all the appearance of infinite scrolling - this is the pseudo variant.  There aren't 755M articles, but there are well over 100.  When you get to 100, you can make a hard click to get more articles, and the process repeats: I gave up after making 10 "load more" clicks, suggesting there are well over a thousand results (indeed, the age of the articles are showing to be several months old; the implication is that the articles might go back as far as their repository contains).

An example of true infinite scrolling serving up all results that pauses the browser as the last of the HTML is waiting to be received would be a client connecting to a site containing limited amounts of display data: an email client, an FTP client, or a music or photos page.  There, the amount of items displayed might be expected to be no more than, say, a few hundred items, and so, that particular site might decide not to implement expensive libraries to manage the display.  Other sites, like Flickr, for example, which does serve up images, has determined that many of its users have more then just a few hundred images, and so, they will implement a more robust pagination library.

And therein lies the answer: performance vs functionality vs cost.  If Flickr went on the cheap and decided not to implement fancy pagination, anyone using their site would walk away as their browsers crashed and burned as the wait time (or memory usage, or both) became too cumbersome.  Question is, are you willing to implement an expensive pagination library (or roll your own) to keep your users happy?  What is your ROI?  How much time do you have?  What features to you need to expose to the end user?  What server resources do you have?  Will your results result in even more data being displayed?

As to that last question, here's a consideration: Google serves up only text.  So you scroll and scroll, you see nothing but text.  Suppose you served up images, like US News and World Report's news thumbnails, or Flickr's image thumbnails.  Now your users are not only downloading the relatively small HTML representing an image, but, once downloaded, the browser has to independently download the actual image - that may come from another site like an advertisement.  So the user's wait time to download data your server is serving up, but it also must further download user-friendly content.  With infinite scrolling, that is a consideration for you: even background downloading of your data must necessarily include downloading content, which could be audio, photo, or video.

Comment: 1) I'm not sure what you're trying to say here, but i'm pretty sure that how the pagination is implemented specific to the application.

2) fair

3) the user has to scroll for any ajax requests to be made to google so this is not accurate.

4) This is implementation specific. But in general it is.

flip side) Can't ctrl-f a page and expect to find something that hasn't been  ajaxed in yet. If the user had scrolled until the server gave up then yeah i guess. If you have the option to "show X" amount of rows in a paginated list you can do this more effectively.

Comment: Though that "benefit" is squandered if you reload a page for any reason. Searching infinite-scrolling pages using the built-in browser text search can be quite a frustrating experience.

Comment: `Because the resulting HTML isn't complete` why would the HTML be broken with infinite scroll?

Comment: Your points 1 and 3 make no sense. Do you think that Facebook is sending malformed HTML to your browser nonstop even if you aren't scrolling? It's still being paginated on the backend, and only sent to your browser on request. It's just not your explicit request; rather, it's implicit by the fact that you're nearing the end of the loaded content. If you quit scrolling, you quit receiving.

Comment: For somebody who knows that there are browsers that will render partial responses, you know little of ajax. Edit: The server sends a complete response, which includes some javascript code that will be executed when the user scrolls down, this code will send an async request to the server which will respond with the data for the next "page" which will be processed and added at the end of the page via javascript... that allows the user to continue to scroll down. With this model the server doesn't have to be working all the time, in fact it is idle waiting for requests, just as usual.

Comment: The benefit of not having to click to get to each page is also a user benefit. This is especially true on mobile devices (even though memory is a con).

Comment: Infinite scrolling does not involve incomplete HTML! There may have been a time when some developers experimented with this technique but today infinite scrolling is implemented by loading a complete page with the first block of content then using a piece of JavaScript to detect when the user is at or near the bottom and then loading and inserting the next block of content into the DOM (pretty easy to do, even with jQuery).

Comment: I thought this forum was about UX forum, not html..

Comment: Yeah, that's an issue to take up with the OP I think.  My answer - and likely all others - apply no matter the OS.

Comment: "everything's on the page, and simple CTRL-F can help them hone in on something" This isn't true is the results are dynamically loaded.

Answer (score 13):

## Google is already testing progressive load...

**Google loads content progressively on Google images**, but they don't do that on web results. There are many reasons for this, as already mentioned in other answers, but the most likely reason is to provide control to users

Think about this: *I know I saw that interesting results on Page2* is way better than *"I have no idea where in this infinite page did I see this result"*.

And `Ctrl+F` won't solve the issue if you have no idea what the result actually said. For example, if you search for `white cat`, you'll probably have hundreds of results on an infinite loading page, all of them for... `white cat`. How will `ctrl+f` help you identify the page you were looking for?

## ... mobile only

However, it seems they're changing their minds and already testing with progressive load, but it seems they're [**doing this only on mobile**](https://www.goamplify.co.uk/blog/google-testing-infinite-scroll-mobile-search/). See the A/B testing below:

[image]

Clicking one or another button doesn't seem like a big trade-off. For most users, it's just a change of label

This actually makes sense, because mobile surfing behaviors are quite different to desktop, and this kind of content loading arguably sticks better
with the tendency to [Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) (PWA) .

Now, are these tests going to change the way Google did things up to date? We don't know. I don't think so, pagination on desktop is very valuable to Google, and we know they aren't big fans of changing their flagship product (Google search). For now, **they're testing with this behavior on mobile**, that's all we know.

Comment: Ctrl+F is doubly pointless, since the results aren't actually part of the page until you scroll to them (give or take a screen or two). In some versions, not even then, since if you want true infinite scrolling, you need to cleanup after yourself instead of letting the page take up more and more memory.

Comment: @Luaan Not to mention that Ctrl+F doesn't work very far away from where you've currently scrolled, either too far up or too far down, even if the results are already loaded.

Comment: "Show more results" isn't infinite load.  It's pagination.  I'm speaking from the server side.  Whether page 3 has 21-30 or 1-30 makes little difference to the backend, presuming the client side is caching 1-20.   the point is the user has to ask for more data (presumably after finding the first data does not suffice).

Comment: @Harper I'm talking from the user side and her interactions

Answer (score 10):

Google follows both models; pagination and progressive loading at the same time but for different pages.

e.g. for [images](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=886&q=steve%20jobs&oq=steve%20jobs&gs_l=img.3..35i39k1j0l9.17168.19039.0.19211.11.11.0.0.0.0.171.1527.0j10.10.0....0...1.1.64.img..1.10.1522.0...0.xQxPx-8-9OM) like here, you can see that there is progressive loading and after a certain moment, a CTA saying "Show more results" come which can show the other set of results but when you search in general like [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=steve%20jobs&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVxtCErovXAhWGNI8KHQKTBxwQ_AUIDCgD&biw=1680&bih=930) then after a certain points, pagination option comes.

[image: Google Image search]

[image: Ggogle normal search]

The reason for this is when you do the image search, you are not looking for something particular and many results can solve your purpose of search but in the case of news and all results, you are looking for something particular and there are high chances that your required answer can arrive on the first page of results.

You can find this quote [here](https://uxplanet.org/ux-infinite-scrolling-vs-pagination-1030d29376f1) too.

> In general, an infinite scroll works well for something like Twitter
>   where users consuming an endlessly flowing stream of data without
>   looking for anything in particular, while pagination interface is good
>   for search results pages where people are looking for a specific item
>   and where the location of all the items the user has viewed matter.

Comment: What is the source for the quoted final paragraph?

Comment: @grgarside check the conclusion part here https://uxplanet.org/ux-infinite-scrolling-vs-pagination-1030d29376f1#.j5av1ps7f

Comment: I can't find that text anywhere in that article using ⌘F?

Comment: @grgarside not the exact words. These are by me but you can find a sentence on similar path on the link I sent. :P
Check conclusion part :)

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for something you haven't quoted then!

Answer (score 2):

I think google does that so that it's easy to paginate & bookmark the search results if the user would like to, compare that to being lost in hundreds / thousands of lines of search results using progressive loading. Maybe..

Comment: Could you expand on your reasoning because as of right now it's more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: didn't I provide my reasoning already ^^ ?

Answer (score 2):

**UX consistency** (over time)

Of all the websites I'm using daily, google search is surely the one that has visually and functionally changed the least throughout the years. They recently changed a few colors for the links I think and that was a pretty big thing for them.

Any change there can potentially harm a billion users daily routines and muscle memory so it seems to me that Google is very conservative with displaying results on Google Search.

Google image search changed a few times, Google News has been refreshed rather newly. But they don't dare perform too big changes on Google Search. I think they would think many times before even changing to something beter so no wonder they won't change it to something worse.

In the end, McDonalds BigMac and cheeseburger haven't changed much and they're still selling. (This answer is not sponsored)

Answer (score 2):

**Pagination adds psychological breakpoints**

If you get to the bottom of the page you have to make a choice, either go to the next page or change your search criteria.

With progressive loading these breakpoints don't exist and users will continue scrolling way longer.

Having breakpoints allows you to abandon bad search keywords and try something else, helping you to find what you're looking for much faster.

That is why search engines have pagination. It has nothing to do with technology.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, not anymore. Since Dec 2022 Google has switched over to progressive loading, so I believe this proves a point that in those years Google product team has been asking themselves the same question.

The path to this decision would be relatively simple in my opinion - Since most users is used to scrolling, not interrupting them would be better than interrupting. What power-users think and the negative impact they experience(mine included), in the vast majority of things, simply does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

### Computational load

Computing search results isn't free.  Asking the search engine for the first 10 results is much cheaper than asking for the first 100 or 1000.

They certainly use a caching system: if they have seen your query 5 minutes ago, they don't hard-recompute the answer again, they give you the same answer they gave the last guy.  Typically this is done by allocating that query to a specific server which handles all queries, say, in that MD5 range.  The server then queries the search engine proper if this is uncached or if some heuristic indicates it is fast-changing.

How large a query set is hard-computed: 10 results?  20? 100?  A big factor is how much the caching system has the space to cache. Search results contain a lot of meta-data -- a LOT -- so the data is bigger than you think.   *Mind you, this is before the blending computations that localize your result. Some of the meta-data is for localization.*

This for sure: extending searches by down-scrolling means *quite a few* more people will be going deeper into search results than they now do... And that means significantly more computing overhead.

Every feature-add can mean having to rack more servers to accommodate the load.  However this one could mean quite a few more servers, with a considerable cost.   Bricks and mortar may also get in the way: They may not even have the rack space.

Comment: "They certainly use a caching system: if they have seen your query 5 minutes ago, they don't hard-recompute the answer again, they give you the same answer they gave the last guy." Really? Google does *user-specific* search taylored for your history.

Comment: @Almo You're talking about the blended result the front end gives you. It is mixing content from several search clusters.  The results from those clusters is what it caches, and then it uses the metadata I mentioned to customize the search further for you.  For instance the node that handles the "pizza" query might get general information about pizza from the main cluster, and information about pizza in Noblesville IN from another cluster.  Both of those can be cached, even though it does further work on selection and ranking customized for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the your answer in the last result of the page 1, then there is no need to go to page 2. In case of progressive loading as soon as you reach the bottom of the page i.e you are seeing last few results it will automatically load the data and increase the load on servers too.

Answer (score 0):

Alongside many of the things already mentioned, there are numerous Accessibility issues with infinite scroll. Cognitively there is the inability to search, not knowing where you are, or where to find previous content.

http://simplyaccessible.com/article/infinite-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

As a user (and full-stack engineer) I am often annoyed by many of the single-page sites out there, and especially progressive loaders. These often scroll the page out from under me, or I loose track as things fade in and out. Or I still have to wait for the content to load, or end up looking at immensely long pages. More designers should opt for page-oriented designs, not the current fad of single page sites, if the pages are too long or slow. Forget it. Even the 'page' I am looking at right now is getting close to what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

"as a designer I believe "Page system" is less efficient than progressive loading inside a single page" ... then you are a lousy designer. The very opposite is true. Progressive loading imposes items on a user whereas paginated results gives the user the power to choose, which is more efficient as the user gets to where they want quicker.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers here are excellent, just to add  what I think there may be another factor at play:

### Nobody cares, because (almost) no one ever goes to page 2.

I failed to find actual research on this, but I'm pretty sure that a very, very high percentage of searches don't leave the top five results, let alone the first page. Not saying it never happens — personally I'd say I leave the first result page about once a month — *but it's not part of the core experience*. As in, Instagram or TikTok relies on an "excellent" (by some definition, not user's mental health) infinite-content-exploration mechanism. For gSearch, the user going past the first results is something that only happens when they basically already failed at doing their job well — serving you relevant content (and ads) as far up as possible.

Since Google as a company is very driven by profit incentive, I can easily imagine that they haven't got around to switch it yet because it's not that relevant.

However I'm just a random guy on SE, and this is all just guesswork :)/

**TLDR: As opposed to feed-based content media, doom-scrolling is not actually an important or even desirable feature of gSearch, therefor Google has no incentive to change the current system.**